# If a normed space $X=\{0\}$ (separable), how to show the closed unit ball of $X^*$ is weak-star metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have a post about this theorem before [If $X$ is separable, then the closed unit ball of $X^*$ is weak-star metrizable. Some calculus helps needed!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424021/if-x-is-separable-then-the-closed-unit-ball-of-x-is-weak-star-metrizable). But what if $X=\{0\}$ (separable), how to show the closed unit ball of $X^*$ is weak-star metrizable?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The dual of $X=\{0\}$ is also $\{0\}$ and if there is something like a unit ball here it’s at most a singleton, hence metrisable. What’s the interest in such a degenerated case?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Because the general proof does not include this case. Yes. $X^*=\{0\}$ and I think the closed unit ball of $X^*$ is $\{0\}$ too. But I don't understand why it is metrizable.

Comment: @AnswerLee there’s only one metric on a singleton. And only one topology too.

Comment: I am so sorry my background is not that strong. Can you be more specific please? Really appreciate!!

Comment: @AnswerLee any finte discrete space is metrisable, but here it's even more  trivial; there is nothing to prove.