# Unit ball of the adjoint space of a separable Banach space is second-countable in the weak* topology.

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, banach-algebras, second-countable, weak-topology

In the proof : If $A$ is separable, then $\Delta(A)$ satisfies the second axiom of countability. ($\Delta(A)$ the set of all complex homomorphisms of $A$.)

I have found they says "It is easy to see  that the unit ball of the adjoint space of a separable Banach space is second-countable in the weak* topology."

But I do not find verifying it trivial, Need some hints to do it.

Comment: Some related questions: [If X is separable, then ball
$X^*$ is weak-star
metrizable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2422000) and [Unit ball
in dual space is
weak*separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2626585)